# Retrieve imported Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've been working with Sequelize for the first time so please be patient))
I've created main Sequelize connection file called "models", which looks like:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
        dbsettings['database'],
        dbsettings['username'],
        dbsettings['password'],
        ...
        }),
    User = sequelize.import(__dirname+'/user'),
    Role = sequelize.import(__dirname+'/role');

User.belongsToMany(Role, {through: 'user_roles'});
Role.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'user_roles'});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

How can I call User model in my controller for `User.findById()` for example?
If I import this file and try call something like `models.User.findById` I get nothing. Please explain the concept to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should export your models, and import to your controller, then use this:

```
  User.findOne({ where: { id: userId } })
  .then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      //raise error or log it
    } else {
      // everything is ok, use returned user object
      console.log(user.name);
    }
  });
```

Just you should remember that any database operation is async call, and Sequelize is returning promise.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! 
1) Modified exports like:
`exports.sequelize = sequelize;
exports.User = User;`
2) Now it is possible to import sequilize connection or a model: `var User = require('../models').User`;